# oracle cursor in stored function, subselect with parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

in a stored function I need to make a "dynamic" query with some sub- sub- selects:

```
CURSOR c_dyn
AS
    SELECT 'CREATE SYNONYM '
        || username_parameter_from_function
        ||'.'
        ||o.object_name
        || ' FOR '
        || o.OWNER
        ||'.'
        || o.object_name
        ||';' AS OUT_SQL
    FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS o
    WHERE o.object_type IN ( 'TABLE', 'VIEW', 'SEQUENCE')
    AND o.OWNER         IN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT x.OWNER
            FROM SYS.dba_tab_privs x
            WHERE x.GRANTEE IN
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT p.granted_role
                    FROM SYS.dba_role_privs p
                    WHERE p.GRANTEE=username_parameter_from_function
                )
        AND NOT OWNER LIKE 'SYS%'
        );
```

Here we have some "sub" selects and a parameter from function. This is NOT working in a function. Any ideas how to "re model" this? or mabye change the function in order to get the same result? or is there a way to make it work AS IT IS....?

Thanks!
M

Comment: what errors are you getting, when you are trying to use it via a function ?

Comment: Post your complete function and error. Your should Open Cursor for select query.

Comment: I got a "table or view does not exist". I solved it setting the select grant directly (even if the user has the DBA and other roles) to the user on the DBA_TAB_PRIVS and DBA_ROLE_PRIVS and DBA_OBJECTS...

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest using [cursors with parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS006)
An example:

```
CURSOR c_dyn(username_param varchar2)
AS
    SELECT 'CREATE SYNONYM '
        || username_param
        || '.'
        || o.object_name
        || ' FOR '
        || o.OWNER
        ||'.'
        || o.object_name
        ||';' AS OUT_SQL
    FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS o
    WHERE o.object_type IN ( 'TABLE', 'VIEW', 'SEQUENCE')
    AND o.OWNER         IN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT x.OWNER
            FROM SYS.dba_tab_privs x
            WHERE x.GRANTEE IN
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT p.granted_role
                    FROM SYS.dba_role_privs p
                    WHERE p.GRANTEE = username_param
                )
        AND NOT OWNER LIKE 'SYS%'
        );
```

Comment: special thanks! that was the best part...:-)
the grants with grant option had to be set for the views...maybe because of the subselect of the fact that it is "wrapped" in a stored function saved in a schema that is NOT SYS....
but thanks!